# Deploy meteor app to digital ocean the second time

Tags: meteor, digital-ocean

Someone set up a meteor app for me on digital ocean, he already published everything there and gave me the source files. Now I updated some files and want to upload the newer files to the server. Can't get a hold of him unfortunately so I'm stuck.

- I can login with terminal to the root server, but then what. How do I get the updated files on the server?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is 'How to upload the file to the server ?'. So, you may google more information on it.

The simplest way, I think you can upload the file via 'ssh'.

```
scp /path/to/file username@a:/path/to/destination
```

Reference: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106480/how-to-copy-files-from-one-machine-to-another-using-ssh

Comment: I tried this, but for some reason when I overwrite the files, the stuff I see when I visit the url is still the same. Not sure what's going on and whether I'm updating the correct files.

Comment: Then, how about checking the file with 'vi' or 'emacs' or whatever editors. You may try to debug by showing some text on the html file such as <h1>Hello, World</h1> (just for testing that the rendered function work properly). Hope you are in luck. !!